# The application “Eclipse” can’t be opened. (macOS Monterey)

Tags: java, eclipse

I downloaded Eclipse on my Mac for school, following these instructions:

> In your browser, go to Eclipse Downloads. Do not use the Eclipse Installer. Instead follow these steps to download and install Eclipse.
>
> Find the Eclipse IDE for Java Developers package (make sure you do not pick the wrong package) and click on the appropriate download link for your operating system (Windows, Mac, or Linux) and architecture (32-bit or 64-bit). There are many other packages but this is the one that you'll need in this class.
>
> Once the download has completed, locate the downloaded file. This file will be a compressed (i.e., a ".zip", or ".tar.gz") file. Uncompress this file into the directory of your choice. It doesn't really matter where you put the Eclipse installation folder as long as you know how to retrieve it. You can optionally create a shortcut of the Eclipse IDE executable file ("eclipse.exe" on Windows, or "eclipse" on Linux, or "Eclipse" on Mac OS X) found in the directory that is created. To start Eclipse you just double-click on the executable file or the shortcut

I downloaded the Eclipse macOS x86_64 version, and moved it into my applications folder. I was able to open Eclipse, and everything works perfectly, and I can work if it's open; but after I close Eclipse and a couple hours go by, I get the following messages once I try to reopen it. "Eclipse quit unexpectedly" and "The application “Eclipse” can’t be opened."

I had the .dmg file in my downloads folder, which might have been the problem. I moved it into my applications folder with Eclipse, and that still doesn't work.

I have tried to delete and redownload Eclipse multiple times, and nothing works.

do you have any suggestions on how I can fix this?

Comment: Did you move the .dmg file to the application folder before or after you tried to run Eclipse? Is there more information when you run Eclipse from the command line?

Comment: You're not running it out of the .dmg itself, are you?

Comment: I would guess so. I'm not a macOS user/expert and only know that a .dmg file is mounted into the file system, but if the configuration area of Eclipse is inside the .dmg file, then it will be initialized on the first start-up and since it contains absolute paths mounting to a different location (which I guess is the case when moving the .dmg file) would not work (I know that for sure for Windows and Linux, but for a .dmg file on macOS I only guess).

Comment: Would my 'workspace' folder also have to be in applications? It's currently is in Documents.

Comment: Having the workspace in _Documents_ sounds good to me (I would guess this is also the default).

Comment: short term solution: don't close Eclipse

Comment: This is happening for me on Monterey on Intel mac. I've installed eclipse-ide from homebrew and it worked, before I first closed it. It's definitely not related to running eclipse from dmg itself. This is most likely a bug in eclipse and should be reported.

Comment: I saw this in Reddit instead of reinstalling you can use this as a temporary solution. codesign --force --deep --sign - /Applications/eclipse.app   [https://www.reddit.com/r/eclipse/comments/s4t79o/eclipse_doesnt_start_after_osx_monterey_121/]

Comment: The bug is described at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=578883 but there are no useful updates there as of the time of this comment.

Answer (score 166, accepted):

Faced the same issue each time I'm restarting the Macbook pro M1, and a random Reddit thread provided me with a way to fix it. Open a terminal and run,

```
sudo codesign --force --deep --sign - /Applications/Eclipse.app
```

Not sure why this codesigning fixes the problem. But seems to be a bug in the eclipse itself. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: thanks, this is an exact fix to the issue, some details on why its happening is here https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202491, basically Eclipse is having components that are not signed or expired, plus this issue is likely to happen after installing new software via eclipse marketplace update site mechanism which modifies the Content of the App bundle, all issues combined makes Gatekeeper block the App, and I guess this solution makes Gatekeeper trust the App bundle again.

Comment: This worked for me, but I had to replace the path with `Eclipse Java.app`.

Comment: For more info checkout: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/684509

Answer (score 8):

I faced the same issue each time I restarted the Macbook pro M1 Max,(Note Eclipse was downloaded via Homebrew) and
tried below but it turned out to be "/Applications/Eclipse.app: Is a directory"

```
sudo codesign --force --deep --sign - /Applications/Eclipse.app
```

the issue was the file structure Eclipse saved was different
(you can check the file structure by cd to the Eclipse through the terminal)
as per the file structure, the path was

```
sudo codesign --force --deep --sign - /Applications/Eclipse\ JEE.app
```

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 5):

running this in terminal works for me :

```
sudo codesign --force --deep --sign - /Applications/Eclipse.app
```

Comment: I am getting "/Applications/Eclipse.app: Is a directory". please help me with it

Answer (score 4):

I had a project that was creating log files in the `/Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/` folder. This caused the signature mismatch. If this happens for you, cd into the above directory remove everything other than the default (eclipse directory). After that, debugger99's suggestion of signing will work.

```
sudo codesign --force --deep --sign - /Applications/Eclipse.app
```

Answer (score 2):

Move the Eclipse app in application folder to bin, reinstall from your .dmg file and it will work again with all your temporary files and setup intact.

Answer (score 2):

This is what actually worked for me:

sudo codesign --force --deep --sign - /Applications/Eclipse\ Java.app

Answer (score 1):

The Issue does not occur for every restarts, but it happened the below cmd worked for me:

```
sudo codesign --force --deep --sign - /Applications/Eclipse.app
```

Thought of creating an alias for it in ~/.zshrc

```
alias signEclipse="sudo codesign --force --deep --sign - /Applications/Eclipse.app"
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue (also macOS Monterey) and I just re-downloaded the dmg, and when moving the app into Applications, it asked me if I wanted to replace the current Eclipse app and I said yes. Now it opened up just fine and is working.

Answer (score 0):

For Apple Silicon Macs (M1/M2), this command worked:

```
xattr -d com.apple.quarantine /Applications/eclipse.app
```

I used it in order to launch BIRT Designer flavor of eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo codesign --force --deep --sign - /Applications/Eclipse.app
```

This command, when executed with elevated privileges, forcefully and deeply signs all components of the Eclipse application bundle on a macOS system using the specified cryptographic identity. Code signing is a security measure that helps verify the integrity and authenticity of the application by ensuring that its code has not been tampered with since it was signed.