# Eclipse quit unexpectedly 2022-06

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, ide

I have started learning Java and am having this error for a few days. I install eclipse and it works just fine. The next day when I try opening the app it doesn't open and I get a message:

"The application “Eclipse” can’t be opened."
and then
"eclipse quit unexpectedly"

on clicking 'show details':

```
-------------------------------------
Translated Report 
-------------------------------------

Incident Identifier: FAF2D9F4-0509-4333-8A9B-7DD02068E9E1
CrashReporter Key:   F85AF088-28E6-8FB6-4EAB-F263B78EA434
Hardware Model:      MacBookAir9,1
Process:             eclipse [27160]
Path:                /Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse
Identifier:          org.eclipse.platform.ide
Version:             4.24.0 (4.24.0.I20220607-0700)
Code Type:           X86-64 (Native)
Role:                Default
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           org.eclipse.platform.ide [13823]

Date/Time:           2022-06-22 21:02:08.7804 +0530
Launch Time:         2022-06-22 21:02:08.6956 +0530
OS Version:          macOS 12.3.1 (21E258)
Release Type:        User
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL (Code Signature Invalid))
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason: CODESIGNING 1 

Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0                                           0x16854ad0 _dyld_start + 0
1   ???                                      0x7062000 ???


Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x0000000000000000  rcx: 0x0000000000000000  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x0000000000000000  rsi: 0x0000000000000000  rbp: 0x0000000000000000  rsp: 0x00007ff7b8ea1be8
   r8: 0x0000000000000000   r9: 0x0000000000000000  r10: 0x0000000000000000  r11: 0x0000000000000000
  r12: 0x0000000000000000  r13: 0x0000000000000000  r14: 0x0000000000000000  r15: 0x0000000000000000
  rip: 0x0000000016854ad0  rfl: 0x0000000000000200  cr2: 0x0000000000000000
  
Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x00000000 
Trap Number:     0


Binary Images:
        0x16850000 -         0x168bbfff  (*) <dd9e80de-fb3b-349b-96a4-46874ad34d11> 
         0x7062000 -          0x7065fff ??? (*) <bf0baa93-fe7a-3039-ac22-e0007dc821f4> ???

Error Formulating Crash Report:
dyld_process_snapshot_get_shared_cache failed

EOF
```

I have done the uninstall-install twice and the same thing keeps happening

Comment: Which Eclipse IDE package (add the exact download link to your question) did you install on which system? It looks like an release candidate of an Eclipse 2022-06 IDE package, but since you didn't tell whether you used the Eclipse Installer, it is also unknown with which Java (both might be the problem here, not final release or not the correct Java).

Comment: The error is "Code Signature Invalid" which usually means the signed part of the app was modified by something.

Comment: At least on Windows the 2022-06 RC1 executables were signed with an expired certificate (see [Eclipse bug 580080](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=580080)). In the final release this was fixed. But this here (`4.24.0.I20220607-0700` means built on June 7, 2022) is not the final release (which was built later).

Comment: @howlger I20220607-0700 is what my Eclipse install shows and it runs correctly. (Eclipse SDK download from the Eclipse Projects site). I did see this error once on 4.23 but after a reinstall it did not happen again.

Comment: @greg-449 For Eclipse SDK it's `I20220607-0700`, but not for an IDE package.

Comment: @howlger Ok, just checked with the Eclipse IDE for Java Developers package - also works fine here.

Comment: FYI another duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70725347/the-application-eclipse-can-t-be-opened-macos-monterey/74249173#74249173 with some interesting answers and comments. And bug link https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=578883

Answer (score 9):

I had exactly the same problem, with Eclipse RCP, and more over this happening on the second launch. Eclipse ‍♂️...

I fixed it this way :

```bash
codesign --force --deep --sign - /Applications/Eclipse\ RCP.app
```

Downloaded from:

```
https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/2022-06/R/eclipse-rcp-2022-06-R-macosx-cocoa-x86_64.dmg&r=1
```

Build id :

```
Eclipse IDE for RCP and RAP Developers (includes Incubating components)

Version: 2022-06 (4.24.0)
Build id: 20220609-1112
```

My report :

```
-------------------------------------
Translated Report (Full Report Below)
-------------------------------------

Incident Identifier: 1943C246-131A-4DC3-AC4B-BC431277597F
CrashReporter Key:   9F468016-722D-5A74-FC64-D618E063DE20
Hardware Model:      MacBookPro16,2
Process:             eclipse [11128]
Path:                /Applications/Eclipse RCP.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse
Identifier:          org.eclipse.platform.ide
Version:             4.24.0 (4.24.0.I20220607-0700)
Code Type:           X86-64 (Native)
Role:                Default
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           org.eclipse.platform.ide [64436]

Date/Time:           2022-07-04 15:27:03.5732 +0200
Launch Time:         2022-07-04 15:27:03.5298 +0200
OS Version:          macOS 12.4 (21F79)
Release Type:        User
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL (Code Signature Invalid))
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason: CODESIGNING 1 

Highlighted by Thread:  0

Backtrace not available

No thread state (register information) available

Binary Images:
Binary images description not available

Error Formulating Crash Report:
_dyld_process_info_create failed with 6
dyld_process_snapshot_get_shared_cache failed
Failed to create CSSymbolicatorRef - corpse still valid ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
thread_get_state(PAGEIN) returned 0x10000003: (ipc/send) invalid destination port
thread_get_state(EXCEPTION) returned 0x10000003: (ipc/send) invalid destination port
thread_get_state(FLAVOR) returned 0x10000003: (ipc/send) invalid destination port

EOF
```

macOs version:

```
ProductName:    macOS
ProductVersion: 12.4
BuildVersion:   21F79
```

Comment: Which build ID is shown in _Help > About Eclipse IDE_? Could you please share the download link of the Eclipse IDE package you exactly talking about.

Comment: Thanks. Can you confirm that you moved the DMG file to the Application folder before running it?

Comment: yeah of course, code sign was applied here: `/Applications/Eclipse\ RCP.app`

Comment: Yes, of course you applied `codesign` in the _Applications_ folder. But the question is whether you can guarantee not to have run the downloaded DMG file before you put the DMG file into the _Applications_ folder? Can you reproduce it with a different IDE package, e.g. [this one](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/2022-06/R/eclipse-java-2022-06-R-macosx-cocoa-x86_64.dmg).

Comment: Ah yes I guarantee that I copied `Eclipse*.app` in the app folder before anything else. Also I wasn't able to reproduce with `Eclipse.app` yet.

Comment: You can't reproduce it at all? By what is it caused? Did you rename something or why is it for you and for a few but not for others?

Comment: I have no idea! I don't mess around with internals like renaming why would I ? I'm barely using Eclipse, I'm an IntelliJ IDEA user, but sometimes I need to go back there. And at some last week point I saw these errors happening twice even after reinstall. Currently the `codesign` trick fixed things. And I'm not alone it seems, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68775300/1273080).

Comment: This just happened again, and I didn't use Eclipse since 2 days. So I closed Eclipse, and it's broken again... Not sure what can cause this, only Eclipse is affected.

Comment: Doing a web search for `macos "Code Signature Invalid"` gives thousands of hits and most of them are not related to Eclipse. If you think it has something to do with how long Eclipse is running or not being used or with macOS Safe Sleep or whatever, it would be up to you to verify it before making any assumptions.

Comment: I'm not doing any assumptions, I'm literally observing something that is **only** happening with Eclipse on my machine. I do not know what or why exactly the signature is lost. I should have contextualized _only Eclipse is affected_ to **on my my machine** but the search you mention is imprecise as well as it is not narrow enough to the case at hand ie "loosing a valid code signature".

Comment: If you want to track it down, see e.g. [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8324476?answerId=33187972022#33187972022) and [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=576299#c2).

Comment: thanks.. this worked for me
"codesign --force --deep --sign - /Applications/Eclipse\ JEE.app"

Comment: Thanks a lot, `codesign --force --deep --sign - /Applications/Eclipse.app ` works for normal installation

Comment: @BenediktKromer thanks to the community, which version was affected by the way ?

Comment: @Brice latest version; basically eclipse allows extension to write in /Applications/, and thus can break the codesign. I think its an extensions fault( in my case...sap code quality is known to be crap) but eclipse should redirect them to the appropriate folder in the first place.

Comment: @BenediktKromer yeah I had the same intuition

Comment: This solution also worked for Spring Tool Suite (STS), being a Eclipse based software.

Comment: Still happening with 4.27.0 and macOs Ventura

Comment: This problem just happened to me with Eclipse 4.30.0 and Ventura 13.4.1. And this suggestion fixed it. But why?