# Unable to start eclipse on Mac : Exception Type: EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL (Code Signature Invalid))

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

Eclipse is unable to launch on Mac & giving following error:

```
-------------------------------------
Translated Report (Full Report Below)
-------------------------------------

Incident Identifier: 36AE9B2B-383A-419D-AA3D-B29CF523D1DD
CrashReporter Key:   A05FEDF2-F14C-94C0-1B65-A7D86D2FA937
Hardware Model:      MacBookPro18,3
Process:             eclipse [35575]
Path:                /Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse
Identifier:          org.eclipse.platform.ide
Version:             4.24.0 (4.24.0.I20220607-0700)
Code Type:           X86-64 (Native)
Role:                Default
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           org.eclipse.platform.ide [716]

Date/Time:           2022-07-01 08:30:29.3080 +0100
Launch Time:         2022-07-01 08:30:29.2679 +0100
OS Version:          macOS 12.4 (21F79)
Release Type:        User
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL (Code Signature Invalid))
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason: CODESIGNING 1
```

Does anyone knows how this can be addressed?

Mac: Monterey version 12.4

Installed Java : OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.2+8-86)

eclipse :  2022-06 version.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72718400/6505250

Comment: thank you !, may be I might need to try using older version then as there is no specific answer available at moment.

Comment: The current release works fine on my mac. It is not clear why some people are seeing this.

Comment: @AshishPatil `4.24.0.I20220607-0700` is not the final release. Download the final release and try again. Please confirm the final release works, so an answer can be added.

Comment: Thank you @howlger, can you please confirm me final release version so that I can give it a try? thanks again.

Comment: @AshishPatil You are the second who face this without saying what exactly has to be downloaded and how it has to be installed to reproduce this. So please download the [final release](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/), try again and tell us whether this works for you or not.

Comment: Sure @howlger, let me give it a try. thanks for sharing this info.

Comment: I have tried using eclipse installer , eclipse IDE & currently getting error about `Catalog could not be loaded. Please ensure you have network access & if needed have configured your network proxy`. Which seems to be issue with my firewall. Let me see why this error is coming now.

Comment: ```codesign --force --deep --sign - /Applications/Eclipse.app/``` worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though it may not be related, but issue which I was facing got resolved after re-install & performing following steps:

1. Downloaded [eclipse installer](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/).
2. My machine requires to use my organisations root certificate for any runtimes / tools.
3. Added these certificates into my JDK's `cacerts`.
4. modified `eclipse-inst.ini` file of eclipse installer & used my JDK path for `-vm` argument instead of the one already available.
5. installed eclipse.

This way my issue got resolved.